how to stick bottom of sidebars?
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="main__left_sidebar"><div class="main__wrap1">Левая боковая панель</div></div>
   <div class="main-content">Основной контент</div>
   <div class="main__right_sidebar"><div class="main__wrap3"> Правая боковая панель</div></div>
 </div>
</div>


While scrolling when it comes to end of sidebar i want to stick it. But when i use sidebarStick() it overflow footer because i used fixed. I am trying to use sticky. Howevere couldnt manage to do it
 if(scrollTop >= contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop) {
            sidebar_content.style.transform = `translateY(-${contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop + margin_bottom}px)`;
            sidebar_content.style.position = "fixed";
        }

How to stick when sidebar come to end so that it will not overlow footer? Full working example:


let left_sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("main__left_sidebar")[0];
let right_sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("main__right_sidebar")[0];

let left_sidebar_content = document.getElementsByClassName("main__wrap1")[0];
let right_sidebar_content = document.getElementsByClassName("main__wrap3")[0];


window.onscroll = () => {
  sidebarStick(left_sidebar, left_sidebar_content, 25);
  sidebarStick(right_sidebar, right_sidebar_content);

}

function sidebarStick(sidebar, sidebar_content, margin_bottom = 0) {
  let scrollTop = window.scrollY; // current scroll position
  let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight; //viewport height
  let contentHeight = sidebar_content.getBoundingClientRect().height; // current content height
  let sidebarTop = sidebar.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY; //distance from top to sidebar


  if (scrollTop >= contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop) {
    sidebar_content.style.transform = `translateY(-${contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop + margin_bottom}px)`;
    sidebar_content.style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    sidebar_content.style.transform = "";
    sidebar_content.style.position = "";
  }
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1460px;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.main__left_sidebar,
.main__right_sidebar,
.main__wrap3,
.main__wrap1 {
  max-width: 290px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  width: calc(100% - 628px);
}

.sidebar-right {
  max-width: 290px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

footer {
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main__left_sidebar">
      <div class="main__wrap1">Левая боковая панель
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>
        <div class="box">6</div>
        <div class="box">7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>Основной контент
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="main__right_sidebar">
      <div class="main__wrap3">Правая боковая панель
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>
        <div class="box">6</div>
        <div class="box">7</div>
        <div class="box">8</div>
        <div class="box">9</div>
        <div class="box">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer <br /> Footer Footer Footer Footer <br /> Footer Footer Footer Footer<br /> Footer Footer Footer Footer <br />
</footer>




You can always use position:sticky and add an offset top to your design.
If you are aiming for a simple css without using any jquery coding, you can use it like this:


.samp-box {
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.mainbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
<div class="samp-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum sollicitudin molestie. Curabitur eu diam id eros vestibulum venenatis vehicula sit amet mi. Cras sed ullamcorper enim, at pulvinar eros. Quisque et mi vitae neque molestie pretium.
    Etiam ultricies eleifend orci vel tincidunt. Phasellus at dui vitae sem laoreet vehicula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed cursus turpis libero, et tincidunt tortor convallis ac.</p>
</div>
<div class="samp-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum sollicitudin molestie. Curabitur eu diam id eros vestibulum venenatis vehicula sit amet mi. Cras sed ullamcorper enim, at pulvinar eros. Quisque et mi vitae neque molestie pretium.
    Etiam ultricies eleifend orci vel tincidunt. Phasellus at dui vitae sem laoreet vehicula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed cursus turpis libero, et tincidunt tortor convallis ac.</p>
</div>

<div class="mainbox">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
      <li>List 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum sollicitudin molestie. Curabitur eu diam id eros vestibulum venenatis vehicula sit amet mi. Cras sed ullamcorper enim, at pulvinar eros. Quisque et mi vitae neque molestie pretium.
      Etiam ultricies eleifend orci vel tincidunt. Phasellus at dui vitae sem laoreet vehicula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed cursus turpis libero, et tincidunt tortor convallis ac.</p>
    <p>Sed tincidunt tincidunt velit, vel semper odio ullamcorper nec. Suspendisse nunc tortor, ultrices sed ullamcorper id, vulputate nec augue. Cras feugiat tellus ac nisi semper mattis vel sit amet felis. Ut est erat, laoreet sed augue sit amet, scelerisque
      convallis nisi. Nulla facilisi. Nam in viverra lorem. Nulla at congue lacus, quis aliquet orci. Fusce arcu lectus, fringilla eget libero vitae, fringilla tincidunt neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin magna leo, lobortis a dui vitae, dapibus
      laoreet velit. Fusce tincidunt sapien ornare placerat congue. Pellentesque laoreet sollicitudin tellus ut consectetur. Sed eu augue semper, facilisis leo in, vestibulum urna. Fusce hendrerit mauris vitae nulla bibendum, eget rhoncus est gravida.
      Vestibulum sapien purus, tristique at lobortis eget, molestie sit amet mi.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque vitae justo porttitor, aliquet ligula varius, iaculis odio. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla condimentum metus tortor, et feugiat erat bibendum et. Donec id pretium neque. Nunc lectus dolor, pretium vitae justo sed, viverra aliquet enim. In
      ut tortor enim. Suspendisse tempor feugiat orci ac ullamcorper. Aenean pharetra rhoncus blandit. Etiam nec erat non sapien molestie porttitor in sit amet dolor. </p>
    <p>Praesent sem lectus, molestie ut fermentum sit amet, faucibus vitae magna. Proin rhoncus eros quis orci hendrerit, non volutpat magna gravida. Quisque scelerisque nulla vestibulum imperdiet lacinia. Quisque ac nisl id lectus tincidunt egestas. Nullam
      tincidunt, leo eget sagittis malesuada, neque risus interdum lorem, id tempus erat lacus vel justo. Cras dictum ipsum diam, at tincidunt mi sollicitudin posuere. Aenean lorem augue, accumsan non magna hendrerit, vehicula vulputate justo. Ut a urna
      ac lacus commodo volutpat vel a metus. Pellentesque a est ut ex euismod elementum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque a rutrum augue.</p>
    <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse luctus ipsum vitae massa consectetur imperdiet. Sed faucibus dui sit amet purus congue placerat. Pellentesque ut tortor tellus. Nulla tellus ante, finibus pulvinar ullamcorper
      tincidunt, vulputate non metus. Ut nec ullamcorper leo, in pellentesque orci. Integer luctus nisi at aliquam egestas. Aliquam neque dui, vulputate vel lectus sed, aliquet bibendum est.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="samp-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum sollicitudin molestie. Curabitur eu diam id eros vestibulum venenatis vehicula sit amet mi. Cras sed ullamcorper enim, at pulvinar eros. Quisque et mi vitae neque molestie pretium.
    Etiam ultricies eleifend orci vel tincidunt. Phasellus at dui vitae sem laoreet vehicula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed cursus turpis libero, et tincidunt tortor convallis ac.</p>
  <p>Sed tincidunt tincidunt velit, vel semper odio ullamcorper nec. Suspendisse nunc tortor, ultrices sed ullamcorper id, vulputate nec augue. Cras feugiat tellus ac nisi semper mattis vel sit amet felis. Ut est erat, laoreet sed augue sit amet, scelerisque
    convallis nisi. Nulla facilisi. Nam in viverra lorem. Nulla at congue lacus, quis aliquet orci. Fusce arcu lectus, fringilla eget libero vitae, fringilla tincidunt neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin magna leo, lobortis a dui vitae, dapibus
    laoreet velit. Fusce tincidunt sapien ornare placerat congue. Pellentesque laoreet sollicitudin tellus ut consectetur. Sed eu augue semper, facilisis leo in, vestibulum urna. Fusce hendrerit mauris vitae nulla bibendum, eget rhoncus est gravida. Vestibulum
    sapien purus, tristique at lobortis eget, molestie sit amet mi.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque vitae justo porttitor, aliquet ligula varius, iaculis odio. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla condimentum metus tortor, et feugiat erat bibendum et. Donec id pretium neque. Nunc lectus dolor, pretium vitae justo sed, viverra aliquet enim. In ut
    tortor enim. Suspendisse tempor feugiat orci ac ullamcorper. Aenean pharetra rhoncus blandit. Etiam nec erat non sapien molestie porttitor in sit amet dolor. </p>
  <p>Praesent sem lectus, molestie ut fermentum sit amet, faucibus vitae magna. Proin rhoncus eros quis orci hendrerit, non volutpat magna gravida. Quisque scelerisque nulla vestibulum imperdiet lacinia. Quisque ac nisl id lectus tincidunt egestas. Nullam
    tincidunt, leo eget sagittis malesuada, neque risus interdum lorem, id tempus erat lacus vel justo. Cras dictum ipsum diam, at tincidunt mi sollicitudin posuere. Aenean lorem augue, accumsan non magna hendrerit, vehicula vulputate justo. Ut a urna
    ac lacus commodo volutpat vel a metus. Pellentesque a est ut ex euismod elementum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque a rutrum augue.</p>
  <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse luctus ipsum vitae massa consectetur imperdiet. Sed faucibus dui sit amet purus congue placerat. Pellentesque ut tortor tellus. Nulla tellus ante, finibus pulvinar ullamcorper
    tincidunt, vulputate non metus. Ut nec ullamcorper leo, in pellentesque orci. Integer luctus nisi at aliquam egestas. Aliquam neque dui, vulputate vel lectus sed, aliquet bibendum est.</p>
</div>
<div class="samp-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam interdum sollicitudin molestie. Curabitur eu diam id eros vestibulum venenatis vehicula sit amet mi. Cras sed ullamcorper enim, at pulvinar eros. Quisque et mi vitae neque molestie pretium.
    Etiam ultricies eleifend orci vel tincidunt. Phasellus at dui vitae sem laoreet vehicula. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed cursus turpis libero, et tincidunt tortor convallis ac.</p>
</div>




it sticks top of sidebar but i need to stick end of sidebar.

I would solve this layout, this way(check the code snippet below) rather. Please check the snippet.


body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  align-items: start;
}

main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100dvh;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  /* adjust according to footer */
}

.box {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar--left {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.sidebar--right {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--left">
  <p>Sidebar Left</p>
  <div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
</aside>
<main>
  <h1>Main Content Goes Here...</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, harum possimus! Quod provident commodi iusto, quidem vitae soluta veritatis exercitationem minus dignissimos neque nihil natus numquam. Fuga voluptas sapiente autem iusto, voluptate quasi
    corporis reprehenderit earum deserunt, repudiandae quam sunt pariatur unde? Beatae eos accusantium ipsam sint maxime quis distinctio dicta quas, vitae tempore quidem eius velit temporibus labore ad fugit quasi sequi quia quam? Dolorem magnam facilis
    vitae ex, sapiente sequi at eligendi rem harum quae! Ipsam repellat nostrum at quasi vero dicta natus blanditiis sint voluptatem laudantium, vitae quaerat itaque cum rem dignissimos animi doloremque minus accusamus reprehenderit. Voluptates quidem
    ad laborum, eos suscipit placeat adipisci. Obcaecati eligendi similique officia? Culpa asperiores excepturi id saepe dolorum quis sunt aut, ex dolores, nulla veniam. Distinctio quisquam deserunt nesciunt impedit, alias optio enim nihil. Odio necessitatibus
    vitae commodi dolorum sint, molestias quisquam mollitia deleniti at asperiores eveniet eos dolores facilis laboriosam repudiandae in debitis distinctio possimus perspiciatis voluptas? A culpa commodi aspernatur ipsam cupiditate, explicabo tempora
    dignissimos soluta delectus maxime, saepe optio accusantium doloremque totam incidunt? Molestias, officia labore temporibus nesciunt earum similique voluptatum necessitatibus maxime placeat reprehenderit quas veritatis provident exercitationem doloremque
    suscipit explicabo dicta amet vitae voluptatem quo porro, fugiat omnis commodi! Quos recusandae laborum et ut aliquid, laudantium animi fugiat? Est fugit debitis ipsum eaque incidunt perspiciatis ducimus vel et deleniti aliquam. Tempore odio praesentium
    numquam? Adipisci nesciunt laudantium at corporis eius porro officia error aliquid expedita eaque possimus inventore, ullam tempora id quasi consectetur, voluptatibus nisi eos ut placeat a. Maiores molestiae numquam fugit, quia aut quam fuga nostrum,
    beatae aliquam exercitationem accusantium repellat rem sunt provident deleniti natus aperiam nam autem corrupti adipisci ab voluptatum nobis atque eius! Neque officia illo, aut esse earum exercitationem. Iure enim reprehenderit sed possimus optio
    deleniti pariatur error non ex sequi blanditiis eaque vitae maiores accusamus sint repudiandae beatae mollitia cupiditate ipsa, eligendi praesentium fugiat repellendus! Eaque nemo sapiente quam perspiciatis laborum ad, quo ducimus autem magnam, corporis
    nulla consectetur a vel molestias. Rem fuga id animi minus corporis. Non alias error autem eum cumque vero fugit voluptatibus molestiae at, nam voluptate magni laborum iste sit natus odit culpa doloremque quos, reprehenderit distinctio commodi. Vitae,
    enim cum ut expedita amet quos obcaecati illum nemo earum ullam. Excepturi illo non sint voluptate itaque eos iusto magni quae, quod unde repellat, molestiae repellendus molestias eum ipsa soluta ipsum recusandae facere quasi, iure tempora impedit
    nesciunt. Ea magnam, maxime, numquam laudantium beatae aliquid dolores, nobis eius ab sit harum ipsum doloribus in modi et nostrum esse quo quibusdam quasi adipisci quam? Libero accusamus, consectetur dolorum ut sequi, culpa impedit sapiente illum
    quae quaerat nemo ipsam deleniti saepe mollitia magnam est inventore quod maiores consequuntur tenetur? Sunt non amet consequuntur, nesciunt enim dolores aperiam eos delectus hic! Voluptates, autem quidem? A reprehenderit eum iure incidunt aut veniam
    eveniet itaque consequatur minima vero maiores, consectetur quos nostrum nesciunt vitae enim perspiciatis eos labore assumenda alias? Ipsa, veniam ea? Pariatur quisquam, aperiam repellendus, repellat possimus tenetur sapiente, rerum error hic praesentium
    debitis facilis iure aliquam accusantium nobis. Ad sapiente animi id fugiat, earum vero enim ipsam optio consectetur eum atque dolorem omnis, deleniti officiis quis cumque? Odio assumenda alias architecto, obcaecati cumque tenetur corporis provident
    sapiente rem. Asperiores, velit ullam porro autem maiores non aspernatur libero hic voluptates ab vel quaerat, consequatur cumque. Pariatur obcaecati suscipit quisquam eos amet nesciunt minus sed magnam, ducimus harum optio, nisi, esse sequi nobis
    tempore eveniet aut doloribus fugit non fugiat. Cupiditate molestiae incidunt vero quidem magnam. Et magnam dicta vero odio dolores laborum veritatis. Unde minima ipsum rem laudantium aspernatur hic debitis ex repellendus, dolores natus animi totam
    sed ad eum quisquam. Pariatur consequatur nisi ea eaque illum porro, distinctio ipsa numquam voluptas, nobis dolore veritatis expedita esse amet suscipit perferendis. Magnam, obcaecati delectus, dolor impedit blanditiis maxime aliquid consequatur
    modi ipsa non voluptatibus error! Aliquid, itaque! Est commodi expedita culpa sunt, nesciunt eum saepe iure totam natus architecto recusandae quas ipsum unde praesentium cupiditate. Doloribus error omnis placeat recusandae sapiente facilis delectus
    fugit id, quibusdam harum dicta voluptatem vero molestias illum eum aspernatur. Neque voluptate saepe eaque sit pariatur amet cum repudiandae nulla obcaecati. Molestias quae quam eveniet fugiat id autem, eos voluptas architecto dolorem ut labore nobis
    sapiente tenetur laborum porro atque aut alias consequuntur ad doloribus, eius reprehenderit nulla soluta. Aliquam a architecto laboriosam autem nulla, iure natus sunt quis saepe provident ducimus dolorum minus itaque modi quidem maiores nesciunt
    voluptatum? Mollitia officiis odit, modi dolor at placeat iusto dicta in, itaque delectus corrupti quibusdam magnam rem. Quia eos a beatae, corrupti numquam rerum fugiat nisi excepturi soluta laboriosam odit impedit iure voluptate repellendus natus
    architecto molestiae, assumenda commodi sed recusandae eaque eum ducimus dolor! Dolorum facilis ut, vitae assumenda saepe enim non optio consequuntur eius? Similique quidem maxime eveniet praesentium, voluptas unde iusto alias? Sit voluptates esse
    quis rerum alias nihil inventore quod tenetur harum, placeat ipsum quos? Quas placeat cupiditate assumenda consectetur nihil esse fugiat nobis, cumque unde. Eveniet repellat quisquam magni atque quibusdam, soluta, fugit quae error ipsum amet ex! Laudantium
    consequatur pariatur mollitia non et ipsa dolor ut doloremque, facilis saepe nesciunt accusamus, temporibus esse iste ratione distinctio? Pariatur nemo, ipsam et quos deserunt possimus sint earum. Ea culpa repellat dolore sequi deserunt, soluta dicta
    quia vel corporis tenetur quis eius esse amet! Tempore aut vero itaque odit reiciendis doloremque ea architecto aliquid ex dicta dolores blanditiis quos perferendis harum, distinctio maxime labore, laudantium illum sequi. Ipsam amet iste itaque assumenda
    laboriosam! Molestias quasi est in dignissimos sed, at libero dolorum sapiente, reiciendis debitis animi eum culpa nulla nesciunt ad quo dolore repellendus inventore soluta praesentium deserunt voluptatem doloribus facere iste? Sed nisi sequi rem
    recusandae, ducimus dolorem impedit alias maiores cumque eos dicta facilis quae ipsam ad repudiandae consectetur voluptate cupiditate et ipsum error. Quas alias deserunt omnis dolorum tenetur quia totam assumenda atque tempora. Nisi laborum quo eaque
    unde. Nobis excepturi sint nulla animi in cum fugit consequuntur porro.
  </p>
</main>
<aside class="sidebar sidebar--right">
  <p>Sidebar Right</p>
  <div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
    <div class="box">10</div>
  </div>
</aside>
<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>




Actually good solution, I was thinking about this. But I need to do it like i said.
